# Characters appear as question marks in MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf8mb4

I have a problem saving unicode characters  in MySql.

Initially my database character set was set to latin1 and unicode strings were  saves as quotation marks. After doing some research I added the following lines to `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

and executed the query:

```
ALTER DATABASE <my_database> CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
```

After restarting mysql, I get an error:

> "org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate  operation: Could not execute JDBC batch   update; uncategorized SQLException for SQL ... Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xBA\xD1\x81\xD0\xB5...' for column 'first_name' at row 1"

Query `mysql> show variables like 'char%'`; returns the result:

```
Variable_name              | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

and query `mysql> show create database <my_database>` gives:

```
| Database  | Create Database                                                       |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| my_database | CREATE DATABASE `my_database` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 */
```

I know this question was answered many time but I tried everything I found in google and still couldn't fix it. Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

After querying SHOW CREATE TABLE, I saw that DEFAULT CHARSET of the table was latin1.

I altered table with `ALTER TABLE my_table CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci`;

After that each column had CHARACTER SET set to latin1, while DEFAULT CHARSET at the end of the query result was utf8mb4

After altering the column with `ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY my_column VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL`, I got rid of the error when saving the value, but it went back to saving the string with question marks. Still haven't found the problem

Comment: Have you changed the *connection encoding* in your Java app (or whatever is producing that error)…!?

Comment: @deceze I have "useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8" in jdbc:mysql URL, is this what you mean?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The _column_ must be utf8mb4.

Comment: Thank you, @RickJames, just add an updated to the original post with that info

Comment: More discussion [_here_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .

Answer (score 10):

1. Make sure you have the correct encoding while inserting into DB. Add the following to your jdbc URL

   ```
   ?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
   ```

   So your final URL will look like this

   ```
   jdbc:mysql://HOSTNAME:PORT/DATABASE_NAME?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
   ```
2. Make sure you create the table with **utf8 character set** and an appropriate **collation** (like *utf8_general_ci*)

Comment: This worked in my case. I had to migrate some columns to `utf8` with `utf8_general_ci`. Also bear in mind that the client machine has its own collation. For example, in my case, for a related issue, for a Java application I had to set these flags `-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -Dsun.jnu.encoding="UTF-8"`. There were issues in regards to Input and Output streams and these two solutions solved it.

Answer (score 9):

So 2 days later i was able to figure it out with the help from comment and other posts.

The issue with unicode was on 2 levels: 
1) How it was saved in MySql 
2) How Freemarker was displaying the value

These are the steps I did that solved the issue:

**STEP1**:  Add the following lines to my.cnf file:

```
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**STEP2:** Run a query

`ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY my_column VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL`

for each column that need to accept utf-8. That fixed MySql encoding. Note: altering the whole database or the table didn't seem to work.

**STEP 3:** Add the following property to `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` bean :

```
<beanclass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem with replacement of cyrillyc letters by question marks was easily solved by deleting the table and creating it again with adding to the end of a 'CREATE TABLE' statement the following:

```
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
```

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS People (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(50), gender char(1), birthDate date, profession varchar(50), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
```

More detaled informaton on encoding issues is provided on the [official MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

Fir you need to open mysql/my.cnf file with any editor after that in mysqld section enter these values like =

enter code here

```
[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
```

after this restart your databse mariadb with command

```
systemctl restart mariadb 
systemctl stop mariadb;
systemctl start mariadb,
```

after this lgin in databse by mysql -u root -p
after login  into databse and run command

```
show variables like "character_set_database";
```

check chracter_set_database and you saw the value of character databse changes latin1 to utf8mb4 and problem has been solved